# Download google reader articles to local folder?

Tags: web-applications, google-reader

Is there any way to have a local store of html or text files for my google reader feeds?
One file per item in the feed?

They go back for years and I want my own copies that I can search through and read without an internet connection.

Kind of like with email, you can have your email on the server and get it through webmail, but you can also save it in an email client for offline use.

I was looking at google's xml feed and json until I was seeing stars.

Is there a program or language that I can use to accomplish this?

Even if I could somehow move all the articles to email and download through client software like thunderbird, that would be great.

I tried FeedDemon but it doesn't go past so many items and I have more content I want.

Comment: I just found http://markos.gaivo.net/blog/?p=1097

It will dump all articles as JSON files.

Comment: Looks promising.  I saw a perl script called Plagger in CPAN that looks like it would work.  It breaks each item in rss into separate email and sends to gmail with a filter.  I could do that and just store the email locally.